# JavaScript password validation with space character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a password validation with the following conditions using JavaScript. My conditions:

1. at least  one digit from 0-9
2. at least one lowercase character(s)
3. at least one uppercase character(s)
4. must contains at least one special character(s)
5. length at least 8 characters and maximum of 20
6. Note : The Space bar also consider as a special character.

I tried

```
(?=^.{6,10}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&amp;*()_+}{&quot;:;'?/&gt;.&lt;,' '])(?!.*\s).*$
```

But it doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Could you _explain_ the code that you tried?

Comment: What is a special character? Is `新` "special"?

Comment: @thg435: Ralph from the Simpsons is a special character

Comment: i'm trying, password validation with the mentioned conditions. for ex : i give a input [space][space][space][space]AA1$. my code doesnt accept this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W]).{8,20})
```

Answer (score 2):

**Basic Solution**

The best way (in my opinion) to handle a set of validation rules is to define a regex for each rule, then iterate the rules and check if they are successful. If any of the rules fail then the whole validation fails.

Something like this:

```
var rules = [
    /[0-9]/,//at least one digit from 0-9, could also use \d
    /[a-z]/,//at least one lowercase
    /[A-Z]/,//at least one uppercase
    /[!%&*\s]/,//special characters, add more as needed. note that \s checks for whitespace
    /^.{8,20}$///length between 8-20
];

var input = "Something1!";

//validate
var pass = true;
for(var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++){
   var rule = rules[i];
   if(!rule.test(input)){
      pass = false;
      break;
   }
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Fz8FZ/)

---

**Advanced Solution**

You could further extend this solution to allow for dedicated error messages to be associated with each rule. Instead of having an array of regex, you would have an array of objects - each containing the regex rule, and the error message.

For example:

```
var rules = [{
    exp: /[0-9]/,
    msg: 'must contain at least one digit'
}, {
    exp: /[a-z]/,
    msg: 'must contain at least one lowercase'
}, {
    exp: /[A-Z]/,
    msg: 'must contain at least one uppercase'
}, {
    exp: /[!%&*\s]/,
    msg: 'must contain at least one special move'
}, {
    exp: /^.{8,20}$/,
    msg: 'must be 8-20 characters long'
}];

var input = "Something1!";

var pass = true;
for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
    var rule = rules[i];
    if (!rule.exp.test(input)) {
        pass = false;
        alert("Error: " + rule.msg);//alert the error message
        break;
    }
}
```

[And here it is in action](http://jsfiddle.net/Fz8FZ/2/)